# GCC - How to statically link a static mono bundle

Tags: c#, gcc, mono, portability, static-linking

I have a .NET application that I want to port to an embedded ARM7 based Linux system. The target is a locked down system running Busybox and I have no write access to the /lib directory (which b.t.w. is empty).I do however have write access to a separate mount point with enough space for my application.

My idea is to compile a static application on a device with the same architecture and copy the binary to the target device. I am using a Beaglebone black for compilation.

**How can I compile my .NET application into a 100% statically linked binary?**

I am aware of the licensing restrictions of Mono (I have a commercial license).

To keep it simple, my application looks like this.

```
/// hello.cs

using System;
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

Step 1: Compile cs code

```
$ mcs hello.cs
```

Step 2: Bundle compiled binary with Mono and output to c code

```
$  mkbundle -c -o hello.c -oo bundles.o --deps hello.exe --static

OS is: Linux
Note that statically linking the LGPL Mono runtime has more licensing restrictions than    
dynamically linking.
See http://www.mono-project.com/Licensing for details on licensing.
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: /root/csharp/hello.exe
   embedding: /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
Compiling:
as -o bundles.o temp.s
```

Step 3: Compile resulting c code

```
cc -o hello -Wall `pkg-config --cflags mono-2` hello.c bundles.o  `pkg-   
config --libs-only-L mono-2` -Wl,-Bstatic -lmono-2.0 ./Lib2/libm.a ./Lib2/librt.a ./Lib2/libdl.a 
./Lib2/libpthread.a ./Lib2/libgcc.a ./Lib2/libc.a -Wl,-Bdynamic ./Lib2/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

***** Warning message receieved (example):

/media/mono-3.10.0/mono/io-layer/sockets.c:992: warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically   
linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for 
linking
```

Step 4: Check dependencies

```
$ ldd hello
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f92000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6f5e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e7f000)
```

At this point, the application works on my development system but not on the target system. I am guessing due to missing libraries as the error message I get is *File not found.*. How can I link the remaining libraries statically?

As an experiment, I've tested a similar approach with a native C application

```
/// hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("hello\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Step 1: Compile with dynamic links

```
$ cc hello.c -o hello
```

Step 2: Check dependencies

```
$ ldd hello
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e26000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f14000)
```

As expected, this application does not work on the target system.

Step 3: Compile with static links

```
$ cc hello.c -o hello -static
```

Step 4: Check dependencies

```
$ ldd hello
   not a dynamic executable
```

This application works on my target system.

I am a total newbie on Linux systems in general and have spent *many* hours trying to find a solution. What worries me a bit is that I'm not even sure if it's solvable :). Any help would be highly appreciated!

Note: If it's impossible to link all libraries statically (for any reason), a solution where these are placed in the same folder as the main application would be totally acceptable. In such a scenario, how would I relink the libraries to ./?

Comment: Did you try using `-Wl,-Bstatic ./Lib2/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` instead of `-Wl,-Bdynamic ./Lib2/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`?

Comment: There is simply no simple way. I believe you have to specify each .dll manually in mkbundle, but there's no way to know which reference requires which dll. You would have easier time installing Mono runtime on target.